# Name of Operation that Brought USA Troops Home at End of WWII?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two

I once heard or read the name of the military operation used at the end of WW-II to bring all of the US troops of the several service branches back to US soil. I have forgotten the name of the operation and would like to learn more about it. As I recall the operation was started right after Nagasaki when Japanese surrender was imminent. In the article or show I am thinking of, it was explained that troops were brought home piecemeal in whatever conveyance was available. E.g. Army troops were given passage on US-bound Navy ships, merchant marine ships, oilers, etc. Others came back in small groups on US-bound aircraft in partial legs of their  complete homeward journey, or across the US to their home towns in a similar manner.

Does anyone know the name of this operation and where I can learn more about it?

Comment: John Dallman, et al: Yes, that would have been real easy had I known the term "demobilization". Please accept my apologies for being so dumb.

Answer (score 4):

This was [Operation Magic Carpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Magic_Carpet). The Wikipedia article explains it, and has a link to the more general article on demobilisation of US forces after WWII.